# Unable to get the feature collection data while exporting as kml file

Tags: kml, geotools, jts-topology-suite

I am trying to get the kml file by giving simple polygon data but not able get exact kml Please suggest me if iam wrong.

code snippet:

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(null);

WKTReader reader = new WKTReader( geometryFactory );

Encoder lEncoder = new Encoder(new KMLConfiguration());

OutputStream lFileOutputStream = null;

lEncoder.setIndenting(true);

try 
{
    lFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("my.kml");

    Polygon polygon = (Polygon) reader.read("POLYGON((20 10, 30 0, 40 10, 30 20, 20 10))");
    lEncoder.encode(polygon, KML.kml, lFileOutputStream);
    lFileOutputStream.close(); 
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
{
    e1.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (ParseException e)
{ 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
catch (IOException e)
{  
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

output getting in KML File

< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
< kml:kml xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:xal="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KML Encoder (like most of GeoTools) works with features not geometries so you need to wrap your polygon in a feature, this gives you the opportunity to add some attributes to make your KML more useful too.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File t = new File("test1.kml");
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();

    builder.setName("test");
    builder.setNamespaceURI("http://www.geotools.org/");
    builder.setSRS("EPSG:4326");
    builder.add("the_geom", Point.class);
    // builder.add("id",Integer.class);
    SimpleFeatureType schema = builder.buildFeatureType();
    ArrayList<SimpleFeature> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      list.add(GenerateRandomData.createSimplePointFeature(schema));
    }
    SimpleFeatureCollection collection = DataUtilities.collection(list);
    exportFeatures(t, collection);

  }

  static void exportFeatures(File outfile, SimpleFeatureCollection features) throws IOException {
    OutputStream outputstream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outfile));
    Encoder encoder = new Encoder(new KMLConfiguration());
    encoder.setIndenting(true);
    encoder.encode(features, KML.kml, outputstream);
  }
```

Comment: thanks .I am able get KML file.How can i add style like line color, fill color to features .

Comment: Please ask another question